# Poor video playback in VLC under bootcamp

Tags: windows-7, macos, video, vlc-media-player, boot-camp

I am using Windows 7 64bit in bootcamp on my aging Macbook and while recently watching a movie using VLC I noticed slight tearing. It is noticeable when the scene changes and very noticeable in action scenes.

Thinking that perhaps the MKV format was the issue, I went into OSX (snow leopard) and played the same video with VLC again and video playback was smooth, very smooth.

So I am very unsure what the issue is.

Under OSX, I am using VLC version 2.1 64bit, and under Windows 7 64bit, I am running VLC version 2.2 32bit but I downloaded the latest 64bit version just in case and the result is the same.

As far as I know I haven't changed anything in OSX's VLC settings.

Checking the video driver for the "Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset Family adapter" in Windows, it appears that I am using the latest version, 8.15.10.1930

Any ideas?

---

EDIT:

I've downloaded MPC-HC x64, recommended as an alternative to VLC, and the same problem there as well. So I guess then the problem is with the video drivers...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly if this will help, but I was comparing media players recently and you might want to take a look at mpc-hc (might be what you downloaded), it's supposed to do better on older machines because it has better DirectDraw support and it uses DirectDraw by default. Don't quote me on that though.

I'm looking at VLC's advanced settings view now, and mine was set to Automatic, but DirectDraw is available as a setting -- wouldn't hurt to try it.
[VLC Settings Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4JZHr.png)

I also don't have much experience with OSX or Bootcamp, but considering that it is a Macintosh at heart and doesn't come out of the box running DirectX, you could try the experimental OpenGL setting.

Comment: This is really a comment and **not** an answer to the original question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment). Please read [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/214174)